# How to add winapi to Lua for Windows

Tags: windows, lua

I've installed Lua for Windows "batteries included" 5.1.4-46.
It doesn't have everything I want.
I'm trying to re-write AutoIt scripts that I use on my personal PC.
I can't find an easy way to access the windows registry.
The [WinAPI module by Steve Donovan](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html) looks like it will give me what I want.
I also want to be able to retrieve file attributes in order to determine if a directory is a junction.

I realize my real issues are not WinAPI, but if I learn how to add it to Lua for Windows, I can hopefully add other Lua addons.
How do I add WinAPI to the Lua installation from Lua for Windows?

Edit:  I've found a binary winapi.dll for Lua 5.1 lua for windows.
[enter link description here](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-01/msg00263.html)

I copied it to the "Lua\5.1\clibs" folder.  I added require("winapi") to the top of a short program.  I had to exit and restart SciTE editor and now it appears to be working.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Post what you tried and what you see.

Comment: I don't know how to add 3rd party libraries to Lua for Windows.  No error messages.

Comment: Thanks for asking me to post the error message  I thought I would have to compile Lua again.  After looking I found the binary, where to put it and now it's working.

Comment: Great. Your edit is an answer. You should create an answer to your own question, this way people can vote on it. Upvote answers you find useful. I believe you can accept your own answer if you find that one to be the most useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third party lib will ultimately (after build) be a DLL. As long as the DLL is on your LUA_CPATH, you can require dll_name and it will load dll_name.dll. There are binary (pre-built) versions of winapi for LuaForWindows, like [v1.0.1](http://stevedonovan.github.com/files/winapi-1.0-lfw.zip). But you are probably better off getting the most recent release and building using one of the build scripts in root folder of [.zip release](https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi/releases). Once you have built, look for the .dll produced and move it to one of the locations on LUA_CPATH, or edit LUA_CPATH to include the folder where you want to put all your Lua extension modules.