# Taking a screenshot with lua in the windows operating system

Tags: winapi, lua

I am trying to take a screenshot of the whole screen on windows using a lua script but I can't seem to find any resource online about it.
Is this even possible?

Comment: With lua alone? Absolutely not. With a winapi/etc. module for lua? Quite possibly but I don't know.

Comment: Can LUA call WINAPI functions? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-to-make-screen-screenshot-with-win32-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008407/how-to-add-winapi-to-lua-for-windows